# Link two models in PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, model, pyqt, signals

I'm new to python programming.Learning on own, with google and you guys help.

Now working on a API project.need to query a list of tasks on UI and on selection of item It should query details of that task.

Its working that way.But I want to keep this task execution in background and show other names on UI. 
I drew a picture of it.

[Here is detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng3aT.png)  I can't post it directly :(

[Screen shot of my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9o48.jpg) HereInstead of task nums,I want to show Shot details

The execution must use task item but on display it should show shot details.

In simple words, I want to show Display list model on UI but when User click,that signal should send tasklist item to execute next query.
How can I access the it? 
I have added my sample code here

```
base, form = uic.loadUiType("uiMainWindow.ui")
class ArtistUi(base, form):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(base, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    Task = MyTasks()
    Task_num = Task.getTask() # List of tasks
    Shot_num2 = Task.getShot() # list of shots


    taskModel = QtGui.QStringListModel(Task_num)
    shotModel = QtGui.QStringListModel(Shot_num2)

    self.mytasks.setModel(taskModel)

    self.show()

    self.connect(self.mytasks, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.Task_Detail) 
    # Task_Detail function will query using Task_num and displays in details listview
```

I found a way to do this is "userRole" but still confused to implement.

Comment: Can any one suggest me a solution?